# Loop Infinito no tratamento de exceção

Tags: java, try-catch

Estou tentando fazer um `try` pra pedir o numero de opção pro usuário, porém quero fazer isso até ele digitar um numero inteiro, fiz um try/catch, mas quando rodo ele e dígito uma `string` ele fica mandando uma mensagem de erro várias vezes, e não consigo identificar o erro;

```
public class CaniveteSuico {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    public Integer Menu() {
        int  opcao=0;
        int checar=0;
        do {
            checar=0;

            System.out.println("\n  ==================================");
            System.out.println("  |     1 - Gestão de Produtos      |");
            System.out.println("  |     2 - Gestão de Vendas        |");
            System.out.println("  |     3 - Gestão de Pessoas       |");
            System.out.println("  |     0 - Sair                    |");
            System.out.println("  ===================================\n");
            System.out.print(" Opção -> ");

            try {
                opcao = in.nextInt();  
                System.out.print("\n");
                checar =1;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Você digitou um caractere inválido! Tente novamente ");
            }
        } while(checar==0);

    return opcao;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que o facto de haver uma exceção do tipo [`InputMismatchException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) faz com que o conteúdo não seja consumido. Logo se está a tentar ler um inteiro e o usuário coloca um texto como `"teste"` é lançada uma exceção e o texto `"teste"` continua lá. Isto significa que quando voltar novamente a fazer `nextInt` para ler de novo, volta a apanhar a mesma exceção. A solução é limpar o que ficou forçando uma leitura em String por exemplo, utilizando `nextLine`:

```
try {
    opcao = in.nextInt();  
    System.out.print("\n");
    checar =1;
} catch(Exception e) {
    in.nextLine(); //"limpa" o que ficou por ler que não era inteiro
    System.err.println("Você digitou um caractere inválido! Tente novamente ");
}
```

É no entanto importante mencionar que deve sempre capturar apenas a exceção que está interessado e não todas como está a fazer utilizando `Exception`, pois em alguns casos pode apanhar outras exceções que não estaria à espera e dar o mesmo tratamento sem se aperceber. Então poderia rescrever capturando apenas `InputMismatchException`:

```
try {
    opcao = in.nextInt();  
    System.out.print("\n");
    checar =1;
} catch(InputMismatchException« e) {
//            ^--- captura apenas o tipo que interessa
    in.nextLine();
    System.err.println("Você digitou um caractere inválido! Tente novamente ");
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema! Abraço!!